# Sefer Daas Mordechai (Pegrimansky)

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books

I read (in the biography of Rabbi Mordechai Pegrimansky; The English translation is titled: The man who never slept) that a supplemental publication called *Sefer Daas Mordechai* was underway at the time of publication (2013) to include original thoughts that Rabbi Pegrimansky discussed during his short life.

Is this publication now available, and if so where?

Comment: ברוך הגבר אשר יבטח בה' והיה ה' מבטחו

Answer (score 4):

There is a bi-annual periodical called *Kol Hatorah*, and each edition has a collection of writings from a deceased *gadol*. I believe one of their editions was dedicated to R' Mordechai Pegrimansky, with a collection of his writings and thoughts. [I will bl"n check this]

Here are links to some of his *Torah*:

[Asufos, Golyon 6 (Shvat 5770)](https://tablet.otzar.org/he/book/book.php?book=159206), originally available as pdf [here](http://www.temanim.org/shtaygen/asufot/6.pdf).

There is a *mamaar* written by him printed in *[Pri Etz Chaim, Cheshvan 5699](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=23406&pgnum=65)*.

Other Torah thoughts of his are quoted [here (comment 38)](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpagefeed.aspx?req=46192&pgnum=549) and [here](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpagefeed.aspx?req=46192&pgnum=411).

R' Moshe Shternbuch collected some stories and memories in his [weekly pamphlet](https://forum.otzar.org/download/file.php?id=55642).

Comment: All of these are prior to 2013.

Comment: If I am correct about the Kol Hatorah, it is post-2013.

Comment: @magicker72 Also, not necessarily entitled Daas Mordechai, but great resources--Chortkov2!

Comment: Whoops... I didnt notice the title. maybe include that in the body of the question?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to [agudah.org](https://agudah.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/JO2003-V36-N02.pdf):

> Although Reb Mordechai left over very few written Torah thoughts,
> a few gems of his great mind remain, and are brought down in sefer Siach
> Yoseph, **by Rabbi Yosef Roth of Bnei Brak, in the chapter entitled Gedulas Mordechai.**

So the book you are looking for is the one written by Rabbi Yosef Roth of Bnei Brak, chapter Gedulas Mordechai

---

I cannot resist sharing one of his thoughts:

> *An unkempt man was touring the Louvre with a group of tourists.
>
> As they were scanning Rembrandt's works the man yelled, "Yogurt!" Everyone thought he was nuts. But he said it again, "It looks like yogurt to me."
>
> Then they passed by the Mona Lisa. Again he exclaimed, "Yogurt!"
>
> A wise man on the tour looked at the fellow. "Let me see your glasses." He gave him his glasses.
>
> "What did you have for breakfast today?" he asked.
> "Some cereal and yogurt," he answered.
>
> The wise man cackled. “Look at your glasses! They are dotted with yogurt! No wonder everything you look at appears as yogurt!”*

*[Parable of Rav Mordechai Pogramanski](https://www.aish.com/sp/pg/97793524.html)*

---

Comment: ''Also, not necessarily entitled Daas Mordechai, but great resources''

Comment: The bounty was auto-selected, but this answer is very unacceptable. Anyone in the know is familiar with that work; it is not at all what I am seeking. I thank you for the efforts, but this is not a true answer.